# SQL Create Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wants to create a function of the average product standardcost for the same color, and using '`red`' to test .  But NULL returned. 
If only run the `SELECT`,`FROM`,`WHERE`,`GROUP BY`, it will work file and return a value.

Here's my code :

```
CREATE FUNCTION avgv (@Color CHAR)
RETURNS CHAR 
AS 
BEGIN
        DECLARE @AVG CHAR ;
        SET @AVG = (SELECT P.Color  AVG(P.StandardCost)  
        FROM AdventureWorksLT.SalesLT.Product P
        WHERE P.Color = @Color
        GROUP BY Color)

        Return @AVG

END
GO
SELECT dbo.avgv('red')
```

Please let me know how to fix, thanks!

Comment: You forgot to specify length in both input parameter and returned result. Also, I assume, you should use `VARchar`. `CHAR` same as `VARCHAR` withoud explicitly defined length means length=1 (one symbol).

Comment: And as already mentioned - your result does nor look like character since you are computing `AVG`.

Answer (score 1):

Input parameter: char -> varchar(100) 
Returns -> char -> int for integer result /decimal(18, 2) for float result 
Remove Group By
Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION avgv (@Color varchar(100))
RETURNS real
AS 
BEGIN
        DECLARE @AVG real;
        SET @AVG = (SELECT AVG(ISNULL(P.StandardCost, 0))  
        FROM AdventureWorksLT.SalesLT.Product P
        WHERE P.Color = @Color)

        Return @AVG

END
GO
SELECT dbo.avgv('red')
```

Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE avgv (@Color varchar(100))
AS 
BEGIN
        SELECT AVG(ISNULL(P.StandardCost, 0))  
        FROM AdventureWorksLT.SalesLT.Product P
        WHERE P.Color = @Color
END
```

Comment: But, still NULL returned.

Comment: SELECT AVG(ISNULL(P.StandardCost, 0))

Comment: this works after using RETURN REAL, also, can you help me to convert it to the create procedures? I want to call it from other language, so we need procedure can hold the parameter(COLOR) to be entered.